# Multiple prepared statements on same page MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have some issues with my code. It seems like I'm not able to have multiple prepared statements which seems a little unusual to me.

I would be glad if you can spot an error or help me because I can't figure out the issue.

My error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/platform/creating_user.php on line 37

I am trying to check if the users email already exists in the database and then register the user.

The code works fine when i dont execute the $check.

```
$check->execute();
```

I would also like some response on my workflow (the way my code is built up). is it okay?

Thanks!

```
<?php 


$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","database");
session_start();


if (isset($_POST)){ 
    if(
        !empty($_POST["name"]) 
      & !empty($_POST["city"]) 
      & !empty($_POST["zip"]) 
      & !empty($_POST["email"]) 
      & !empty($_POST["tel"]) 
      & !empty($_POST["password"])
    ) {

        $name       = encrypt($_POST["name"]);
        $city       = encrypt($_POST["city"]);
        $zip        = encrypt($_POST["zip"]);
        $email      = encrypt($_POST["email"]);
        $tel        = encrypt($_POST["tel"]);
        $password   = encrypt($_POST["password"]);


        if(!empty($name) && !empty($city) && !empty($zip) && !empty($email) && !empty($tel) && !empty($password)) {

            $check = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?");
            $check->bind_param('s', $email); 
            $check->execute();

            if ($check->num_rows == 1) {  
                header("Location: index.php");
                die();
            } else {


            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, city, zip, email, tel, password, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
            $insert->bind_param("ssssss",$name, $city, $zip, $email, $tel, $password);


            if ($insert->execute()){ 

                $db->close();
                $_SESSION["user"] = $email;
                header("Location: created_user");
                die();

            } else {
                header("Location: create-user");
                die();
            }

        }

        } else {
            header("Location: create-user");
            die();
        }


    } else {
        header("Location: create-user");
        die();
    }
} else {
    header("Location: create-user");
    die();
} 


?>
```

Comment: `$db->prepare` returns a `boolean` this mostly means there is something wrong with the DB Connection.

Comment: add this for diagnostic 
if (!$check = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?")) {
                echo $db->error;
                exit(0);
            }

Answer (score 0):

On php.net I found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

> mysqli::prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error
>   occurred.

So this mean something is wrong with your `$db` object. This could be:

- Wrong password
- Wrong username
- ...